# Access uploaded file, from a multipart/form-data, without providing a name to the property of the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an AngularJS web app (legacy codebase) which is sending a request to my Rails API to upload a file. COnsider the case where I have a file named `this_is_my_file.ddd`.

When uploading the said file, I can access the following parameters at the Rails controller:

```
{
  "controller" => "my_controller",
  "action" => "my_action",
  "this_is_my_file.ddd" => #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f90290c58f8 @tempfile=...
}
```

The problem here is that the web app is not defining the name of the property containing the file, so Rails automatically defines that property with the name of the file itself. It forces me to handle the request without objectively know the name of the property (I need to do stuff like this `params.permit!.to_h.first.second` to get the file) as it will change from file to file.

Changing the behavior of the AngularJS web app is not a possibility.

Is there another way to access the file, in a more objectively way, like getting the name of the file from another place in the request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change that horrible client code I would just modify the parameters on the recieving end so that you get a fixed key that you can permit and work with:

```
params.merge(
  files: params.values.select { |v| v.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile) }
).permit(:foo, :bar, files: [])
```